# How to configure l3ACL dpdk application for gateway

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to configure l3ACL application for gateway.l3fwd ACL Dpdk application is running in Mellanox NIC.using dpdk (dpdk-stable-20.11) as a shared library.

Edit:
Earlier scenario  of Connection setup of l3fwd acl testing using Trex Traffic generator
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSpSC.png)

In this scenario the packets are forwarded by the L3fwd ACL application of DPDK in the direction from Port 1 to Port 0 of the Trex traffic generator. This was made possible by including the MAC address in the --eth-dest flag with the MAC address indicated by the Trex at initialization. On including this MAC address the packets were detected by the Rx side of the traffic generator i.e Port 0.

Current scenario

This setup was modified to mimic gateway level deployment to test L3fwd ACL as shown in the connection diagram attached below.

Connection Diagram attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nU3p.png)

In this setup the ports connected to the traffic generator are replaced by two machines that mimic the external network and internal LAN network as shown. We have tried to ping the external and internal network without running DPDK application. The ping in the network is working without enabling DPDK. The L3fwd ACL application was subsequently started with the command given below with the physical MAC address of the machine which was replaced at the port 0 side which was earlier connected to the traffic generator. Port 0 received the traffic from the L3fwd ACL application in the case of the traffic generator. The main difference is that we are including a physical MAC address with the --eth-dest flag in the gateway scenario whereas an emulated MAC indicated by the traffic generator was used with --eth-dest flag to forward the packets in the working setup for L3fwd ACL using traffic generator in a loopback manner.

The physical MAC address of the interface of the Rx side of external network machine connected at Port 0 is not receiving the traffic destined out from the L3fwd  ACL application. The configured Route entry in rule_ipv4.db is    R0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0/0xff 0.

Not able to trace the packet at the interface with Mac address given in –eth_dest parameter.After starting l3fwd acl destination host is unreachable.
Command used for L3FWD ACL

```
./dpdk-l3fwd-acl –l 1-7 –n 4 -- -p 0x3

--config=”(0,0,1),(1,0,2),(0,1,3),(1,1,4),(0,2,5),(1,2,6),(0,3,7)” --rule_ipv4=”/root/rule_ipv4.db” –rule_ipv6=”/root/rule_ipv6.db” –eth-dest=0,next-hop-MAC-here
```

How to configure the l3ACl dpdk sample application for gateway?

Comment: Please update the following in the ticket to better understand the query. 1. Code snippet of customized application (at least what is different from orginal l3fwd ACL example). 2. Is the orginal l3fwd example working for the data traffic ? 3. How are you generating data traffic. 4. If pcap file share screenshot or link t o pcap. Please note the question intention is not clear

Comment: For Original l3fwd ACL example also we are not able to get the traffic  at Rx side of next hop interface.Attaching the connection diagram in Question.Can we use eth-dest command line parameter to route the packets to internal network.If otherwise ,please provide suggestions on how to route the packets to internal network to external network.

Comment: Requested for your custom application code snippet. Did not find any. As per update sample application is not setup correctly. How is data generated is not shared. What is dst Mac address in use not explained. Neither pcap or screenshot of packets shared. Yet @Indu you are asking to provide suggestions. I am not clear with your intentions, please clarify what is your real question.

Comment: s your question `I am unable to run l3fwd application properly, need help?`. If yes please update your question and share information about cfg file nad traffic generator.

Comment: are there any updates?

Comment: @Vipin Thanks..I have updated the original post..Please check

Comment: Thanks for the update, from your update you mentioned  you have got l3fwd a cl working. Currently you are facing some issue with custom application. Is this the right understanding? If yes once again your application  code snippet is missing. Dump of a l are missing. What is port 0 and port 1 is missing, you havementioned youare not able to tracepacketthis is not clear are you using pkt_dump api?

Comment: L3fwd ACL is not working the current scenario.(Please check 2 nd diagram).In the first connection set up  using Trex Traffic generator as shown in first diagram it was working)

Comment: I would love to spend time to understand why it fails with debug and works with trex. Personally I have been able to use trex, dpdk pktgen, packets, scapy and all works for me.

Comment: After l3fwd acl application is started ,we checked the tcpdump o/p of Port 0 of Rx connected to external network .There we are not receiving any traffic.

Comment: We are facing this issue with sample l3fwd ACL application of dpdk.

Comment: I have already shared I would like to spend time with your environment for debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPDK example code l3fwd-acl works on IP packets only. For non-ip it is dropped in the function `process_one_packet`. While using external packet generator like TREX, DPDK_PKTGEN, SCAPY, PACKETH, PCAP replay with IP packets are not dropped and ACL lookup is performed. Packets matching with the condition are forwarded through DPDK ports while no match are dropped.

In your current scenario, connecting to the interface to actual network could lead to

1. ARP or RARP packets to be generated
2. LDAP packets to be generated
3. If connected over managed switch VLAN packets are generated.

In all above cases these are treated as non-IP packets leading to drop of the same. Hence the recommended way is to use by adding static ARP entry to end machines or switch. This will eliminate the ARP and RARP packets.

Note: If the external devices are not configured with promiscious mode, please use `--eth-macaddress` to help l3fwd-acl to update the MAC address too.

Comment: Thanks Vipin.Discussion with you helped us to have a clear understanding of l3ACL and the configuration issues we were facing.